# finding highest value in an array of objects not exceeding a certain value - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, properties

I have a an array of objects and want to find the player with the highest score which also does not exceed a certain score (for example 20 points). How do I do so?

```
    let playerScores = [ 
  { player: 'Dealer',
    score: 19,
    cards: 'A of ♥, 5 of ♦' },
  { player: 'Player1',
    score: 18,
    cards: '10 of ♦, 8 of ♦' },
  { player: 'Player2',
    score: 23,
    cards: '6 of ♦, 6 of ♥, J of ♠' }
    ]

console.log(playerScores)
// iterates through playerScores
for (let i in playerScores) {
    if (playerScores[i].score > 20) {
        console.log(playerScores[i].player + ' BUSTED!')
        // removes the object with a score over 21 from the array
        playerScores.splice(i,1)
    }
    return playerScores
}
```

Comment: what does not work with the code?

Comment: I need to find the player with the  highest score, which in this case would be Dealer with a score of 19.

Comment: yes, exactly! I want to find the player which has the highest score which is lower than 20.

Comment: what about ties?

Comment: then I would need to present all players who have the same score

Answer (score 3):

You can filter the data first, sort it by score and then take the first one:

```
let filteredData = playerScores.filter(p=>p.score<=20).sort((a,b) => b.score-a.score);
let result = filteredData.length ? filteredData[0] : undefined;`
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution is to make a function that takes the limit score and iterate over the elements of **palyerScores** and find the match element look at the example below

```js
let playerScores = [
    {
        player: 'Dealer',
        score: 19,
        cards: 'A of ♥, 5 of ♦',
    },
    {
        player: 'Player1',
        score: 18,
        cards: '10 of ♦, 8 of ♦',
    },
    {
        player: 'Player2',
        score: 23,
        cards: '6 of ♦, 6 of ♥, J of ♠',
    },
];
function getHighestScore(limitScore) {
    let highestScore = 0;
    let player = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < playerScores.length; i++) {
        if (
            playerScores[i].score > highestScore &&
            playerScores[i].score < limitScore
        ) {
            highestScore = playerScores[i].score;
            player = Object.assign({}, playerScores[i]);
        }
    }
    return player;
}
let highsetScorePlayerNotExced20 = getHighestScore(20);
console.log(highsetScorePlayerNotExced20);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a chained check of conditions and add the object if necessary to the result set or replace the object with one with a higher score.

```js
var playerScores = [{ player: 'Dealer', score: 19, cards: 'A of ♥, 5 of ♦' }, { player: 'Player1', score: 18, cards: '10 of ♦, 8 of ♦' }, { player: 'Player2', score: 23, cards: '6 of ♦, 6 of ♥, J of ♠' }],
    value = 20,
    result = playerScores.reduce(function (r, o) {
        if (o.score >= value) {
            return r;
        }
        if (!r.length || r[0].score < o.score) {
            return [o];
        }
        if (r[0].score === o.score) {
            r.push(o);
        }
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let playerScores = [
    { player: 'Dealer',
        score: 19,
        cards: 'A of ♥, 5 of ♦' },
    { player: 'Player1',
        score: 18,
        cards: '10 of ♦, 8 of ♦' },
    { player: 'Player2',
        score: 23,
        cards: '6 of ♦, 6 of ♥, J of ♠' }
];

const maxLimit = 20;

const maxScorePlayer = playerScores.reduce((prev, current) => {
    if (current.score >= maxLimit) {
        return prev;
    }

    return (prev.score > current.score) ? prev : current
}, { });
```

You can check how reduce function works [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let playerScores = [ 
      { player: 'Dealer',
        score: 19,
        cards: 'A of ♥, 5 of ♦' },
      { player: 'Player1',
        score: 18,
        cards: '10 of ♦, 8 of ♦' },
      { player: 'Player2',
        score: 20,
        cards: '6 of ♦, 6 of ♥, J of ♠' }
    ];

    var highestScore = Math.max.apply(Math,playerScores.map(function(o){
                                         score = 0;
                                         if(o.score != 20) {
                                             score = o.score;
                                         }
                                         return score;
                                     }));
                         
    console.log(highestScore);
```